# Publish/deploy exe from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Trying to deploy a little C# app to another server...in visual studio am doing the publish from the menu,it creates a publish folder & subfolders,etc.  Copy those to another machine and try to run the setup.exe there - gets following error, also tried just copying the exe created and the .exe.config and get same error.  When publishing, selected "install from CD" so all file paths relative to install directory...so something is not right!

Messages below:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:                         CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01:                       loadadjusterphotosapp.exe
  Problem Signature 02:                       1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03:                       4e81f332
  Problem Signature 04:                       mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05:                       2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06:                       4d8c19ca
  Problem Signature 07:                       344a
  Problem Signature 08:                       119
  Problem Signature 09:                       System.IO.DirectoryNotFound
  OS Version:                                 6.0.6002.2.2.0.272.7
  Locale ID:                                  1033
```

thanks,

Phil J.

Comment: The `System.IO.DirectoryNotFound` exception is telling you that something in your code is trying to access a directory that doesn't exist. I would suggest adding some diagnostic code to your application that does a better job of catching exceptions and reporting the errors.

Comment: ok - the only reference to a directory is in the app.config file or appname.exe.config file rather...

Answer (score 0):

I get this error and seems to be due to missing libraries.

In my case it was to do with windows media player.  My program only worked on computers that had Visual Studio installed.  No idea what the actual fix is though.